# How to loop through an array of objects in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to access the url of an object stored in an array, but I'm getting errors no matters what methods I'm using.

```
let userPhotos = currentUser?.photos

    for var i = 0; i < userPhotos!.count ; ++i {
        let url = userPhotos[i].url
    }
```

Here I get

> Could not find member 'url'

and with a foreach:

```
for photo in userPhotos {

        Utils.getImageAsync(photo.url , completion: { (img: UIImage?) -> () in

        })
    }
```

I get:

> '[ModelAttachment]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

My array is `var photos: Array<ModelAttachment>?` and my ModelAttachment looks like this:

```
class ModelAttachment :Model {
var id: String?
var url: String?
var thumb: String?
}
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong would be great :)

Comment: If you declare your photos array as: `[ModelAttachment]`, you should be able to use the for loops.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Unwrap and downcast the objects to the right type, safely, with `if let`, before doing the iteration with a simple `for in` loop.

```
if let currentUser = currentUser, 
    let photos = currentUser.photos as? [ModelAttachment] 
{
    for object in photos {
        let url = object.url
    }
}
```

There's also `guard let else` instead of `if let` if you prefer having the result available in scope:

```
guard let currentUser = currentUser, 
    let photos = currentUser.photos as? [ModelAttachment] else 
{
    // break or return
}
// now 'photos' is available outside the guard
for object in photos {
    let url = object.url
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the end it works by modifying your code like this:
`for object in userPhotos! as [ModelAttachment]`

Comment: You can write simply `for object in userPhotos!` and it will work. But it defeats the purpose of optional types.

Answer (score 6):

Your `userPhotos` array is option-typed, you should retrieve the actual underlying object with `!` (if you want an error in case the object isn't there) or `?` (if you want to receive `nil` in url):

```
let userPhotos = currentUser?.photos

for var i = 0; i < userPhotos!.count ; ++i {
    let url = userPhotos![i].url
}
```

But to preserve safe nil handling, you better use functional approach, for instance, with `map`, like this:

```
let urls = userPhotos?.map{ $0.url }
```

Comment: note that `for;;` syntax does not exist in Swift 3 anymore

Comment: This has been removed from Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the simple NSArray **in** syntax for iterating over the array in swift which makes for shorter code.
The following is working for me:

```
class ModelAttachment {
    var id: String?
    var url: String?
    var thumb: String?
}

var modelAttachementObj = ModelAttachment()
modelAttachementObj.id = "1"
modelAttachementObj.url = "http://www.google.com"
modelAttachementObj.thumb = "thumb"

var imgs: Array<ModelAttachment> = [modelAttachementObj]

for img in imgs  {
    let url = img.url
    NSLog(url!)
}
```

[See docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121)

Answer (score 0):

The `photos` property is an **optional** array and must be unwrapped before accessing its elements (the same as you do to get the `count` property of the array):

```
for var i = 0; i < userPhotos!.count ; ++i {
    let url = userPhotos![i].url
}
```

Comment: This was supported formerly but has been deprecated since Swift 3.0. Please use formal Swift syntax